# Intersecting three polygon layers in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, coordinate-system, union, intersect

I have three data sets of San Francisco, **TerraSAR-X**, **ALOS-PALSAR**, **Radarsat2**. I have extracted **KML** files using **Envi Sarscape**.

[image]

In order to find the intersection of these areas, I have converted these **kml**'s into **polygon shapefiles** using:

> Conversion Tools ---> From KML ---> KML To Layer
>   Conversion Tools ---> To Shapefile ---> Feature Class To Shapefile
>   (multiple)

[image]

Each of those **shapefiles** have the following coordinate system when I used the properties from **ArcCatalog**

[image]

But when I used the following **toolbox** to extract the **intersection** **shapefile**

> Analysis Tools ---> Overlay ---> Intersect

The extracted **shapefile** will be as follows!!

[image]

**What's the problem?**

---

**Edit to answer radouxju**
Union would give the following result

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that nothing is wrong with your coordinate systems / projections of the three shapefiles?

Comment: What if you project the three shapefiles to a projected coordinate system (PRCS), such as UTM? I believe `Intersect Tool` is using planar mathematics for the geographical coordinate system (WGS). Although that issue is patched at 10!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange Union output is common with shapefiles with invalid geometries. Shapefiles are expected to follow "right hand rule" (walking the perimeter of the geometry, the feature is always on the right hand side), while KML is expected to follow "left hand rule" (except Google calls it "right hand rule", after a different rule, involving the thumb and fingers).  If the polygons are wrapped incorrectly, then optimiztions in the Union code will exclude figure instead of ground.

Whenever you get unexpected output from *any* [overlay](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-overlay-toolset.htm) operation (Union, Intersect, Erase,...) with a shapefile data source, you should always use [Check Geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/check-geometry.htm) to validate your data source.  If it fails validation, then the [Repair Geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/repair-geometry.htm) utility can be used to correct the polygon windings.

If you convert the KML to file geodatabase instead of shapefile, any improper KML winding would be either detected or corrected, since topology checks are performed when FGDB geometries are written.  This is yet another reason to use file geodatabase instead of shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like the sort of output I would anticipate from the *Intersect* tool.

If you are totally stuck, the *Feature To Polygon (Data Management)* tool will differentiate out the common area between your three polygons. If you then convert each polygon to a point and spatially join this back to your new polygons dataset you should be able to get a count of how many polygons each point intersects; you will be looking for those with a score of three.

A more detailed article on this workflow is available here: [More adventures in overlay: counting overlapping polygons with spaghetti and meatballs](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/11/13/spaghetti_and_meatballs/).